# I need BIOS R0140C5 for my Sony VAIO SVS13

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios, sony-vaio

can someone give me link to download BIOS R0140C5? This is stock bios on laptops. I didnt find any information, mb who has Sony VAIO S-series with this BIOS can make backup of it. My SDD is broken, and it has unusual connector, which also broken. So i cant set any other ssd/hdd. I connected usual HDD instead of BD using special connector/ All was worked fine, but i updated BIOS to R0143C5, and I got "OS not found" at my laptop. Can s1 help to find stock bios?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the boot device settings. We could give it to you but it won't solve your problems your configuration has already been lost

Comment: Yes, i tryed to boot in UEFI mod and Legacy. Also combined with different boot priority. But It's boots from USB-flashdrive with liveCD. And it easy can see my disk. I tryed to re-install windows, but installer sayed me like that: You cant install at this disk, because it's not bootable in BIOS. This problem appeared after i updated Bios, mb stock version can solve it. Do you have some option in BIOS where U can choose like "RAID 0" or "Hide"?

Comment: And there is no "Secure boot options".

Comment: Did you happen to attempt to load an unlocked version of the BIOS?  Because your likely going to need to contact Sony for the firmware in question.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote about "Secure", because i thougth U will ask "Did you off Secure boot. At previous version of BIOS wat option "RAID 0"/"Hide". I think it was foe stock SSD, which had two disks in raid 0 massive. When i hid it - windows began boot from HDD connected to Blu-ray Sata port. I think, it can work, if i try to recover stock bios. I dont see any other ways.

Comment: I thougth about that (unlocked), but i know, what it will be problem to get back to stock bios after that.

Comment: First lets simply confirm if your disk a MBR or GPT disk?  I am telling you, even if you were to get this firmware and restore it, your configurations were set to the default.  The firmware unless it was an unofficial unlocked version can be made to work.  **If you used or use the unlocked firmware I cannot help you.**

Comment: My disk is MBR. I tryed to re-install windows on another disk in 2 ways: 1-st way at UEFI-mod- GPG-disk and GPD USB-flashdrive with Windows. Result - system was installed, but after first reboot, i saw same black screen with "OS didnt found". 2-nd way at Legasy boot - MBR-disk ang MBR flashdrive. At the first step of installing windows was an error "Cant create/format partition, because chosen disk isnt bootable (like didnt set boot from him at BIOS boot device priority.

Comment: If unlocked bios will not help me, i would not be able to restore it, thats why i dint used it.

Comment: But now it can be last way, because another i cant find

Comment: 1-st, I'd like to use official r0140c5 version, if it will not help me, i try to use unlocked version, but dont know which exactly

Comment: If you are not even willing to try other solutions then I can't help you.  When you find the version of the firmware you will be back with this exact same problem.  Its entirely your choice.  You should update the question with all the information you have shared.  I would also read through the question and remove anything that might sound confusing.  Lots of shorthand words for things with some very specific details.

Comment: Then can u give me link with unlocked Bios?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Sony's eSupport](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-find.pl?mdl=SVS13) site?

If you don't find the version, post your exact model number and I'll see what I can do. :-)

Comment: Product name is SVS13A1Z9RB, model number is SVS13AA11V

Comment: They didn answer me yet. I askes them yestуrday.

Comment: I've reached out to a friend at Sony. I will let you know what I hear. But don't get your hopes up. When I first asked him, he said it was a very old BIOS.

Comment: Yes, it's old, but it worked. Thank you any way.

Comment: Please verify that model number, or tell us what country you're in. My friend didn't find that as a US model.

Comment: Model number is correct, It was bougth in Russia. S/N 27554560 5000116, date of manufacture is 2012-07

Comment: http://www.sony.ru/support/ru/product/svs13a1z9rb All I could find there was the R0142C5 BIOS. My friend is still trying to see if he can find it for you.

Comment: yes, i tryed this version

Comment: Sorry to report my friend couldn't find the BIOS you're looking for. :-(